# xmemory0 throws exception at deallocate when using std:: collections

Tags: c++

I have a C# program mainly for UI which uses a c++ dll for the logic.

Lately i switched compiler from platform toolset VS 2012(v110) to VS 2017(v141), since then i recieve an exception(without description) everytime it trys to release a std:: collection.

Example:

```
{
    std::string str = "";
}
```

I tried the same with std::map, std::stack and std::list all of these get a exception in the file xmemory0 within the function _Deallocate. This does not happen when i create a simple c++ console application, so i guess it has something todo with c++ used within a c# application.

Using a custom Allocater for std::list seemed to work but i would like to know the reason why upgrading the compiler leads to such a problem.

Comment: Not enough information here to help.

Comment: @Ben what else do you need? i will try to do my best to give you all the information you need.

Comment: What was the exception? Have you tried with the debug heap turned on?

Comment: How do your C# and C++ code interact?

Comment: Any chance the string got exchanged between two C++ dlls compiled with different versions of MSVC?

Comment: @Ben It is a bebug assertion at the expression _CrtlsValidHeapPointer(block)

Comment: @Quentin no the little code i posted is enough, but i think it has something todo with different versions of msvc ... i do not know how to find it

Comment: One way this can happen (among many) is if you have 2 C++ DLLs, one allocates memory and the other frees it, but they are built targetting different versions of C++ runtime, e.g. debug vs. release or different version numbers. If you think it is incompatible versions, you need to rebuild the whole thing and all dependent DLLs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly i found the cause, between 2012 and 2017 they added a new delete operator. So for allocating the string it used our new operator and for deallocating it used the standard delete operator.

(do not ask why we override those operators(not my decision)...)